# HttpClient doesn't report exception returned from web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using `HttpClient` to call my MVC 4 web api. In my Web API call, it returns a domain object. If anything goes wrong, a `HttpResponseException` will be thrown at the server, with a customized message.

```
 [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
  public Person Person(string loginName)
    {
        Person person = _profileRepository.GetPersonByEmail(loginName);
        if (person == null)
            throw new HttpResponseException(
      Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, 
                "Person not found by this id: " + id.ToString()));

        return person;
    }
```

I can see the customized error message in the response body using IE F12. However when I call it using `HttpClient`, I don't get the customized error message, only the http code. The "ReasonPhrase" is always "Not found" for 404, or "Internal Server Error" for 500 codes.

Any ideas? How do I send back the custom error message from the Web API, while keep the normal return type to be my domain object?

Comment: What web server you are using, IIS or ASP.NET Web Server?

Comment: I'm using IIS on a Win 2008 R2. Again, it's ok when I call it using a browser.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

(Putting my answer here for better formatting)

Yes I saw it but HttpResponseMessage doesn't have a body property. I figured it out myself:  `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;`. The sample code:

```
public T GetService<T>( string requestUri)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response =  _client.GetAsync(requestUri).Result;
    if( response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result;
    }
    else
    {
        string msg = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            throw new Exception(msg);
    }
 }
```

Comment: You should be wary of invoking `Result` directly from `ReadAsAsync<T>` because this can cause intermittent threading issues. Instead, try: `var contentTask = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();` followed by `contentTask.Wait();` and then `return contentTask.Result;`

Comment: @Sixto: Can you describe the threading issues? The [Result](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd321468(v=vs.110).aspx) docs say "The get accessor for this property ensures that the asynchronous operation is complete before returning." It sounds like a call to `Wait` is built in.

Comment: Why do people do this: response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result ... the task hasn't finished yet Result will always be null ... jeez

Comment: @Calvin I am unable to catch request timeout exception that way. Can you confirm if it works for Request Timeout scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

I factored out some of the logic when grabbing the exception from a response.

This makes it very easy to extract the exception, inner exception, inner exception :), etc

```
public static class HttpResponseMessageExtension
{
    public static async Task<ExceptionResponse> ExceptionResponse(this HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage)
    {
        string responseContent = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExceptionResponse>(responseContent);
        return exceptionResponse;
    }
}

public class ExceptionResponse
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string ExceptionMessage { get; set; }
    public string ExceptionType { get; set; }
    public string StackTrace { get; set; }
    public ExceptionResponse InnerException { get; set; }
}
```

For a full discussion see [this blog post](http://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2016/07/getting-web-api-exception-details-from-a-httpresponsemessage/).

Answer (score 0):

The custom error message would be in the 'body' of the response.

Comment: Yes I saw it but HttpResponseMessage doesn't have a body property. I figured it out myself:  `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;`. The sample code:

    public T GetService<T>( string requestUri)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response =          _client.GetAsync(requestUri).Result;
        if( response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result;
        }
        else
        {
            string msg = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                throw new Exception(msg);
        }
     }

Comment: Actually by body, i meant the content of the response.