# How to debug this Windows Auth issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication

I am getting an exception during a service call after I have changed our auth mechanism to Windows Auth. I'm sort of losing the will due to being unable to diagnose this. It seems like a very generic error buried somewhere in the depths of the MVC auth.

The error message is:

```
Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

My call stack is this (with my method call remove for privacy):

```
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +137
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +65
System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +97
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +17
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +48
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +48
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +137
```

This is in my web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Here is the code I use:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = true
};

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
var result = await client.GetAsync(uri);
result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

`EnsureSuccessStatusCode` throws because of the 500 returned from the call.

It is not hitting any of my code. I have breakpoints on the entry point at the other end. So what is causing this? How can I debug it and get enough information to fix it? I feel like there must be some way to get more information that I do not know about?

I don't necessarily want a solution if someone could tell me how to go about diagnosing the issue?

Comment: Do you get 500 errors when running against visual studio's built in web host or are you seeing these when running against a fully installed version of IIS?

Comment: Running using the built in web host. Everything worked that way in a prototype application I wrote and sadly moving to full IIS isn't an option as it's how we work in our company...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12113071/960812) answer:

```
if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    string msg = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    throw new Exception(msg);
}

result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

Obviously I wouldn't recommend this for production code (or as a way to use async code) but this will get you exact error messages for debugging your service calls.

As it is, error debugged and fixed within five minutes of actually getting the error message.